# How do I view the SummaryReport after running JMeter script via command prompt?

Tags: jmeter

I ran my JMeter script for 2 Users through the command prompt. The script ran successfully , but how can I view the SummaryReport?

This was the output I saw:

```
Press any key to continue . . .
C:\Users\rp091176>C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\JMETER\J_Scripts\PERF_SOA_CompanySetup_NBCU.jmx
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\JMETER\J_Scripts\PERF_SOA_CompanySetup_NBCU.jmx
Starting the test @ Tue Nov 25 13:22:33 PST 2014 (1416950553909)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
summary +      1 in   0.1s =   11.9/s Avg:    84 Min:    84 Max:    84 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +      5 in     1s =    6.6/s Avg:   147 Min:    23 Max:   319 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 2 Finished: 2
summary =      6 in     1s =    6.9/s Avg:   136 Min:    23 Max:   319 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Nov 25 13:22:35 PST 2014 (1416950555205)
... end of run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When run jmeter plan using non-gui mode , By default JMeter does not save summary results to file. Either you have to save as JTL and view it in the summary listeners later or run with the summary listeners.

Please read - http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

Comment: Hmm, why do you say "JMeter does not save summary results to file"? Aren't JTL files the files that the summary results are saved into?

Comment: I said by default it does not save , before run in non-gui mode , you must set JTL file with same name which you use as command for non-gui.

Comment: Ic.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

Save the results file as JTL and open it from that location.
It might take some trial and error to find out exactly how to configure it but it will be worth your effort.
Do read the link mentioned in the above answer as well for further insight in to this section  of Jmeter.